# Issue in spliting data in Txt file while converting from RDD to DataFrame in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I reading data from a text file as RDD and converting into DataFrame but I am not getting the desired output.

Code -

```
val myFile = sc.textFile("car.txt")
val df = myFile.map(_.split(" ")).map(line => Text(line(0))).toDF()
df.show()
```

where Text is the case class

case class-

```
case class Text(field: String)
```

Data in the car.txt file -

```
hyundai honda
honda maruti
maruti honda
```

Output when executing -

```
+-------+
|  field|
+-------+
|hyundai|
|  honda|
| maruti|
+-------+
```

Why am I not getting all the data from the text file in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are `split`ting the data on spaces and then only outputting the first element of that (first word) -> `line(0)`

If you just want the lines, then you can cut out the `.map(_.split(" "))` and then just use the `line` (no `(0)`)